# Error on Wikipedia about Dilations

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, homothety

Looking at Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation), the definition of a scale factor has two definitions of a scale factor which are clearly not equivalent.

**Is definition $(1.)$, or comment $(2.)$ the correct one of a "scale factor" in this context? In other words, can the ratio of magnification, dilation factor, scale factor, or similitude ratio be negative?**

It states:

> $(1.)$ "In Euclidean geometry, a homothety of ratio $\lambda$ multiplies distances between points by $|\lambda|$ and all areas by $\lambda^2$." The next sentence then clearly refers to and defines $|\lambda|$ to be the "scale factor."

However, this is a problem as it later describes $\lambda$ to be the scale factor (i.e. where $\lambda<0$):

> $(2.)$ "The image of a point $(x, y)$ after a homothety with center $(a, b)$ and **scale factor $\lambda$** is given by $(a + \lambda(x − a), b + \lambda(y − b))$."

Comment: @saulspatz You cannot say the first definition refers to the scale factor as being $\lambda$ here. If you continue reading, it states the figure is an enlargement when the scale factor exceeds 1. Therefore, the scale factor is referring to $|\lambda|$ here, and not just $\lambda$ for precisely the case when $\lambda<-1$.

Comment: I'll delete my comments if you promise to stop pinging me.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the [answer](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math133/fall07/geometrynotes3b.pdf)! I appreciate the time others took to help me. Looking on p. 117 (i.e. p.8 of 23 on the pdf) the definition of "ratio of similitude" is given which is the positive real number of a transformation on a metric space of which a dilation is being scaled by. Thus, the first number must be referring to $|\lambda|$ when talking about the ratio of magnification or dilation factor or scale factor or similitude ratio.

Thus, $(2.)$ is wrong and really should say the "ratio" instead of "scale factor."

Comment: I'm glad you've resolved the question to your satisfaction, but keep an open mind. Mathematical discourse regularly involves *signed* values —signed distances, signed areas, signed angles— that can go by *unsigned* names —"distance", "area", "angle"— as suits an author's purposes. Context (and/or explicit disclaimers) makes usage clear. The Wikipedia entry could perhaps be more *self-consistent*, but in the grander scheme of things, one isn't "wrong" to call the signed $\lambda$ a "scale factor". *When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.* —Humpty Dumpty

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? Are you saying you define a signed $\lambda$ as a scale factor? What is a signed $\lambda$? I would like to hear your definition too even though it may vary from mine. I don't get what signed distance has to do with distance here as those are different topics.

Comment: I don't have "*a* definition"; I write whatever seems to convey an idea clearly. ... I'm sure that I've written something like "dilation with scale factor $-1/2$" a time or two here. I don't think anyone was confused by the usage, and I'm not "wrong" to have written it. Likewise, Wikipedia terminology differing from that in some random PDF doesn't make either one "wrong". Mathematical language, like any language, has its dialects, accents, and styles. Certainly, there are plenty of terms upon which we agree ("pi", "triangle", "generating function"), but we're *allowed* some flexibility, too.

Comment: While terminology may differ from author to author, one hopes that it doesn't change in the middle of the singular paper or book we happen to be reading. In this regard, Wikipedia deserves a bit of leniency: after all, the "wiki" in "Wikipedia" means that authorship is *crowd-sourced*. (Almost) *Anyone* can edit an entry. So, dozens of people with differing terminological biases may have written bits and pieces of that "Dilation" entry. Inconsistencies are inevitable. On the plus side, when you *notice* an inconsistency, you're *allowed* (one might say *obligated*) to fix it.